# I am having an error using expo-video-player in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have no code in the app just a simple expo react native app...created the app and installed `expo-av` and `expo-video-player` and im getting the following error:

```
Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/netinfo" from "node_modules\expo-video-player\dist\index.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem running the following command:

> yarn add @react-native-community/netinfo@5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

install

```
yarn add expo-video-player or npm install expo-video-player
install expo-av @react-native-community/netinfo
```

and import

```
import { Video } from 'expo-av'
import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'
```

and render

```
<VideoPlayer
  videoProps={{
    shouldPlay: true,
    resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
    source: {
      uri: '{YOUR_URL}',
    },
  }}
  inFullscreen={true}
/>
```